# Typescript string | string[] find the array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular, typescript1.5

I am finding the length of string|string[] , I have variable as a data type of `var stepData : string | string[]` .
Some times  I am getting a single string value , also possible to get the list of string . Using the length of array I am doing some other operation.
 In my code I am doing some `for` loop function using that `stepData.length` . Here the sample my code

```
const stepData: string|string[] = this.$stateParams.stepData;

 // Here two possible length value I am getting 
 // If the stepData is string[] get length of array value 
 // If the stepData is string  get the length of string
 // The `lengthVar` depends on below for loop

 if (stepData.length > 0) {
        var lengthVar = stepData.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < lengthVar; i++) {
          // Inside im writing some ajax call
     }
 }
```

How to find the exact array length of `stepData` I want array value only using I am calling AJAX method inside . If any suggest I am trying any wrong or give ur valuable suggestions please.

Comment: it's not very clear what you want. do you want to deffrintiate between the two possible types of `stepData`? if so, how? and what's this `dataId`? please explain what you want better.

Comment: What's the matter with .length ? That does exactly what you want on both types.

Comment: Exactly I want the `stepData` , when its string and when its string[] finding the length of array i am calling AJAX inside for loop

Comment: No, If I am getting `string[]` I got diffrent length , if `string` i am getting the length of string value which is inside the `stepData` . But below for loop executed that much time called , if the value is `string`. This is the problem I am facing

Comment: @AlexG  Below `for` loop I am executing only length of array only , if the value is `string` . Its excuted more times created more number of data inside Database,

Comment: No, sorry, you're still not clear on what you want to do. Very simply: (1) if it's a `string` what should happen? (2) if it's `string[]` what should happen?

Comment: How to know if its string and string[] .  I am executing for loop using the `stepData` .

Comment: Inside `for` I am iterating `stepData.length` . So If its string only one time I should iterate ,If its `string[]` I should find the length of string array that much time I iterate.

Comment: I am not getting any error , but the value of `stepData.length` is getting different , some time I got only one `string` I should iterate only one time . Instead my `for` loop executed the length of string times.

Comment: Example `stepData = "abc"` the for loop excuted 3 times because my code is `stepData.length` . But i want only one time . This is the problem I am facing @NitzanTomer , @AlexG

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like:

```
const _stepData = (typeof stepData === 'string') ? [stepData] : stepData;
```

then iterate it as an Array. More consistent, less bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You're questions is very unclear, but I'll take a guess that you're asking how to know whether the value in `stepData` is a `string` or `string[]`, if that the case then:

```
if (typeof stepData === "string") {
    // stepData is a string
} else { 
    // stepData is a string[]
}
```

or

```
if (stepData instanceof Array) {
    // stepData is a string[]
} else { 
    // stepData is a string
}
```

You can make your `stepData` not a `const` and then:

```
let stepData: string|string[] = this.$stateParams.stepData;

if (typeof stepData === "string") {
    stepData = [stepData];
}

// now stapData is string[]
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment on the question:

> Inside `for` I am iterating `stepData.length` . So If its `string` only one time I should iterate ,If its `string[]` I should find the length of string array that much time I iterate

In that case, your code must be able to differentiate between `string` and `string[]` with a check at runtime. A simple check to differentiate between the two would be `typeof stepData === "string"`, which will be `true` for `string`s but `false` for `string[]`s.

```
if (typeof stepData === "string") {
    // here stepData is a string
} else {
    // here stepData is a string[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if some variable is a string or string[] you could use the keyword instanceof:

```
if(stepData instanceof Array<string>) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

or

```
if(typeof stepData === "string") {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: you can't use `instanceof` on `string` (or `String`), and checking if it's `"object"` doesn't get him so far as it can be a lot of things